# Maven Transitive Dependency issue: I need upgrade dom4j to 2.1.3 but group id different than older version of Dom4j 1.6.1

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Transitive Dependency issue: I need upgrade dom4j to 2.1.3 but group id different than the older  version of Dom4j 1.6.1

```
    mvn dependency:tree
 +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile


<groupId>dom4j</groupId>
<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>

<groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
<version>2.1.3</version>
```

Added a newer version of dom4j  as a dependency to dependencymanagement tag. However, I do not see a newer version reflected on transitive Dependency.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
<version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Please suggest?

Comment: you need to exclude your old and include your new dependency.

Comment: Accept the answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as i know, you can't just change the version of the transitive dependency in hibernate-entitymanager. But, you can exclude old dependency and include new version of that dependency like below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```